# jQuery SlideDown next row by row

Tags: row, slidedown, slideup

1)  INPUT BOX 1       AMOUNT         INPUT BOX2 

 [Add More .] when click this button should slidedown like below

1)  INPUT BOX 1       AMOUNT         INPUT BOX2 
2)  INPUT BOX 3       AMOUNT         INPUT BOX4   (x)  (close button)

 [Add More .] when clicked again slideDown to 3rd row.

1)  INPUT BOX 1       AMOUNT         INPUT BOX2 
2)  INPUT BOX 3       AMOUNT         INPUT BOX4   (x)  (close button)
3)  INPUT BOX 5       AMOUNT         INPUT BOX6   (x)  (close button)

 [Add More .] when clicked again slideDown to 4th row.

when click close that row should slideUp.